# Android push notifications - how to get the device id

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am stucked with the process of creating a push notification using Google's cloud notifications.

What I am working on is the part where I am supposed to get the device id of the device so that I can use that device id later on, when I need to send a push notification.

So I have this code:

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) 
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
```

and I thought that this line

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

Was going to get me the device id so I can store that somewhere. But I think I am way off track in how this is actually meant to work. Could someone please explain to me how I can get the unique id of the device so I can store it for further push notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'unique id' of the device is actually a unique id based on device and app installation. The `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context)` will give you that unique ID. If you are looking to get it after it registers, it is passed into the onRegistered method of the GCMIntentService that you have to override to make it work.

Comment: ah so I am not totally off, and just need to overwrite the onRegistered method? Would you have a link to sample code which does this effectively?

Comment: you don't NEED to override the onRegistered method. the id gets saved and you can get it with the GCMRegistrar method. the ID is one of the parameters of onRegistered. Just send a request to your server with that ID in it.

Comment: do you mean with this method: GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId() ...if so, it is returning an empty string.

Comment: it returns an empty string if your device isn't registered. check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#getRegistrationId(Context))

Comment: The GCMRegistrar class is now deprecated.  You can learn the more current way of using GCM (including the registration process and such) [in the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html).